How I do scraping in a web page that show information with scroll and not with index?
I'm learning web scraping, and i'm trying to get data from a page that show information with scroll, What can I do in this scenario?, Is there a function to make the entire page load? I am using selenium and beautifulsoup
This is the code:
html = driver.page_source
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

games = bs.find_all('div', {'class': 'GVj7ae imso-medium-font qJnhT imso-ani'})
for game in games:
    print(game.get_text())

I read about a script that can scroll the page, but doesn't work, just give to me duplicated data, for instance, if the output is
Apertura · Jornada 1 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 2 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 3 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 4 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 5 de 17

The script for scroll given to me:
Apertura · Jornada 1 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 2 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 3 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 4 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 5 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 1 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 2 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 3 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 4 de 17
Apertura · Jornada 5 de 17

This is the script:
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

scroll_pause_time = 2 
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

html = driver.page_source
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

games = bs.find_all('div', {'class': 'GVj7ae imso-medium-font qJnhT imso-ani'})
for game in games:
    print(game.get_text())

driver.quit()



what's the url?

This one: https://www.google.com/search?client=opera-gx&q=partidos+de+liga+mx&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&si=ACC90nw9vMMdwL91whQ4n-NcljM143f3JvZl4TM_hvFSavH6DxhM68nwhpUpFrgEtIyxVqexrdwH9mpql3VkflsXToKZLmXQp_CsfB80IHWz5WIyej5VecCOzFB0dZOkfAvRiM3SZuHkMeaLo_0sYN-PiYkgInSzGUflkPuMm0_0wrQ958DDB2I%3D&ictx=1&ved=2ahUKEwi2h4_TnKWHAxWVMUQIHS22BM0QyNoBKAB6BAgVEAA#cobssid=s&sie=lg;/g/11y5frthr0;2;/m/0446bd;tbbs;hd;;;;2024-07-05T22:45:00Z

You are scrolling the main window, the matches are in a scrollable div.
Here is a quick example of how to do it:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Liga+MX#sie=lg;/g/11y5frthr0;2;/m/0446bd;bs;hd;'
driver.get(url)

header = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-title]'))) 
total_matches = int(header.text.split(' ')[-1])

container = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[jsname=GMIS8e]')
while True:
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);', container)
    time.sleep(0.2)

    if len(container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-title]')) >= total_matches:
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);', container)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        break


match_tables = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.liveresults-sports-immersive__match-tile table')
print(f'{len(match_tables) = }')
driver.quit()

But I suggest you use an API instead, there are many free football APIs.
